# Check/uncheck element through link inside Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

So I have a folder with 2 placemarks in it.  One of them is hidden on load while the other is visible.  I'd like to have a link in the description of the visible one to hide/show the hidden one.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the standalone Google Earth, however you can with the Google Earth plugin for web browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Google Earth plugin, this is one way of doing it.

First assign each placemark an 'id' - so in the KML file you need to edit the code that says

```
   <Placemark>
   <name>Placemark 1</name>
```

to

```
   <Placemark id="placemark1">
   <name>Placemark 1</name>
```

and the same for Placemark #2

then you have a javascript function like the one below, which is executed by adding a button through the balloon description [(see this example page for how to do that)](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#javascript_in_balloons)

```
    function togglePlacemarks() {
         var pm1 = ge.getElementById('placemark1');
         var pm1 = ge.getElementById('placemark1');
         if (pm1.getVisibility() == true) {
    pm1.setVisibility(false);
            pm2.setVisibility(true);
     } else {
    pm1.setVisibility(true);
            pm2.setVisibility(false);
     }
    }
```

In the example code to execute JS from a balloon, you would change the following line

```
     balloon.setContentString(
    '<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'Running some JavaScript!\');">Alert!</a>');
```

to

```
      balloon.setContentString(
    '<a href="#" onclick="togglePlacemarks();">Toggle Visibility</a>');
```

Finally, if you only wish to have a simple (ie only 2 placemarks), then perhaps you should use the example code to create your placemarks instead of creating and loading a custom KML file. In which case, when you create the placemarks (through this line of code)

```
     placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
```

You would do this

```
     placemark1 = ge.createPlacemark('placemark1');
     ...etc
```

and also

```
     placemark2 = ge.createPlacemark('placemark2');
     ... etc
     placemark2.setVisibility(false);
```